# How to make a function to do the mapping

Tags: scala

I am using source to process data from a csv file. I am trying to refactor some of the code because when I save it I am using double map on the same line

```
   _contents = source.getLines().map(line => format.extract(line)).map(fields => factory.newItem(fields)).toList
```

the line above works but I am trying to add a function so

```
 _contents = source.getLines().map(line => mapData(line)).toList




   def mapData(line: String):Unit = {
    val data = format.extract(line)
    data.map(fields => factory.newItem(fields))
  }
```

this is what I have so far. problem is when I hover over fields in '''`factory.newItem(fields)`''' I get Type mismatch, expected:Array[String], actual: String I understand what the issue is I just cant think of how to fix it

problem is when I hover over fields in '''`factory.newItem(fields)`''' I get Type mismatch, expected:Array[String], actual: String I understand what the issue is I just cant think of how to fix it

Comment: What is the signature / return type of `format.extract` ?

Comment: It makes a string into string array. so it takes a string and makes it a string array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is:

```
_contents = source
  .getLines()
  .map(line => factory.newItem(format.extract(line)))
  .toList
```

Comment: Thank you I used ur suggestion and refactored my method to work. You are right I needed to factory.newItem all line rather than each element of the line array
 so I did      factory.newItem(data) instead of mapiing it again